# Rspec send params to subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I wrote a small service, which need params: `[:search][:area], [:search][:floor]` etc. 
I write test:

```
subject { AwesomeService.new(params) }
let(:params) do
  {
    "search" => {
      'area' => object1.area,
      'floor' => object1.floor
    }
  }
end
```

But my test fails(manually work perfectly). When I debug my service in test mode, `params[:search][:floor]` is `NULL`. How can I fix my params in test?

Comment: what's going on with indentation???

Comment: can you post your test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `params` object in rails does not care if you look for values in it as symbols or strings:

```
params[:search][:floor] == params['search']['floor']
```

A `Hash` in ruby, though, is different - if you insert strings as keys, you need to query it with strings.

```
param_hash[:search][:floor] != params['search']['floor']
```

You stub `params` as a hash. This means you should either set it with symbols instead of strings, or use [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html).

```
subject { AwesomeService.new(params) }

let(:params) do
  ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new {
    "search" => {
      'area' => object1.area,
      'floor' => object1.floor
    }
  }
end
```